# wp_enqueue_script adding conditional statement not working

Tags: conditional-content, wp-enqueue-script

This is the code im using in my functions file:

```
add_action('init', 'sort_out_jquery_pngfix_frontend');
function sort_out_jquery_pngfix_frontend() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    if(!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', array(), NULL, true);
        wp_register_script('dd_belatedpng', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/dd_belatedpng.js', array(), NULL, true);
        $wp_scripts->add_data('dd_belatedpng', 'conditional', 'lt IE 7');
    }
}

add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'register_theme_scripts');
function register_theme_scripts() {
    if(!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('modernizr', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr-1.7.min.js', array(), NULL, false);
        wp_enqueue_script('googlemaps', 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false', array(), NULL, true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('dd_belatedpng');
        wp_enqueue_script('sc_wc_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/function.js', array('jquery', 'dd_belatedpng'), '1.0', true);
    }
}
```

I'm using `$wp_scripts->add_data('dd_belatedpng', 'conditional', 'lt IE 7');` to add a conditional statement to this script as per the documentation I can find on-line but its not working. The conditional code is not shown but the js file is.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Why support ie 6 and keep this browser alive? WP 3.2 doesn't

Comment: Please move solution to the answer, that would be more in line with site's mechanics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From quick look at code this conditional only seems to be processed for styles and not scripts.

Comment: That's what I was going to suggest.

Answer (score 5):

It is a long shot, but you might try *registering* the script, *then* adding in the conditional, and *then* enqueueing the script:

```
// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'dd_belatedpng', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/dd_belatedpng.js', array(), NULL, true );
// Attempt to add in the IE conditional tags
$wp_scripts->add_data('dd_belatedpng', 'conditional', 'lt IE 7');
// Enqueue the script
wp_enqueue_script( 'dd_belatedpng' );
```

I don't know that it will work, though

**EDIT**

Based on the related Trac ticket, it appears `$wp_scripts` doesn't support this method.

You may just need to pull the script out of the `wp_enqueue_script()` system, and echo the IE conditional-enclosed script call inside of a pluggable function hooked into `wp_print_scripts` or `wp_head`. It's certainly not ideal, but if this is a single-use client Theme, then you don't have to worry about someone else needing to deregister the script.

Comment: Thanks Chip I will try that tomorrow when I'm back at work. I will make one amend though and that's to put the `wp_register_script` and `add_data` in an `init` hook rather than the `wp_print_scripts` hook.

Comment: @Brady As far as I could see from the file I took as reference, `init` works perfect for `register`. @Chip Bennet As this is just so genious!: +1 :)

Comment: updated question with new code trying your suggestion Chip and it doesnt work :(

Comment: updated answer with a less-than-ideal, but not absolute-worst-case, option.

Answer (score 5):

This is the work around I had to put in place since WP doesnt support what I was trying to do

**functions.php**

```
add_action('init', 'sort_out_jquery_pngfix_frontend');
function sort_out_jquery_pngfix_frontend() {
    if(!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', array(), NULL, true);
        wp_register_script('dd_belatedpng', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/dd_belatedpng.js', array(), NULL, true);
    }
}

add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'register_theme_scripts');
function register_theme_scripts() {
    if(!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('modernizr', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr-1.7.min.js', array(), NULL, false);
        wp_enqueue_script('googlemaps', 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false', array(), NULL, true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('sc_wc_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/function.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    }
}
```

**footer.php**

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<?php wp_print_scripts(array('dd_belatedpng')); ?>
<script>DD_belatedPNG.fix("img, .png_bg");</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: +1 for having a working solution, but wired anyway...

Answer (score 3):

Just found a partial solution for this via `$is_IE` in wp-includes/vars.php!

```
function emporium_enqueue_scripts() {
    global $is_IE;
    if( $is_IE ) {
        wp_register_script( 'emporium-focus' , get_template_directory_uri() . '/library/focus.js', '', '',  true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'emporium-focus' );
    }
}
add_action('init', 'emporium_enqueue_scripts');
```

That seems to load library/focus.js on an `if IE` basis but there's nothing in core to do any IE version conditionals for scripts. Looks like a [Trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10891) on the subject has been shelved for the time being.

Comment: Thanks for the input and idea. Though is_IE will target all IE versions not just IE6.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are putting it in the footer.  Did you look at the end of the page for the JS file?

Comment: Yes I looked and its not that.

Answer (score 1):

This works for scripts too. But only in one situation: If the script was `registered` first. You can't go straight for `enqueue`. You'll have to do: `register` -> `add_data` -> `enqueue`. This is both for scripts as for styles the same rule.

Comment: Isn't that [what I just said](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20873/wp-enqueue-script-adding-conditional-statement-not-working/20877#20877)? :)

Comment: Oh, ehm... yea. If this is wrong I will downvote you ;)

Comment: As you should! :)

Comment: I've tried it in this order and it doesnt work. See edited code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example for Wordpress 4.2 and above.

**This first example was previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30780638/2232458).**

```
    wp_register_script("ie_jshandle",
                 get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/jsSpecificIE.js",
                 array(),
                 '1.0',
                 false );
    wp_enqueue_script("ie_jshandle");
    wp_script_add_data("ie_jshandle", "conditional", "lt IE 9");
```

**You can also use `$wp_scripts` variable like this:**

```
function wpse_20873_enq_scripts() {
global $wp_scripts;
        wp_register_script("ie_jshandle",
                     get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/jsSpecificIE.js",
                     array(),
                     '1.0',
                     false );
        wp_enqueue_script("ie_jshandle");

        $wp_scripts->add_data("ie_jshandle", "conditional", "lt IE 9"); 
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "wpse_20873_enq_scripts");
```

**[wp_script_add_data reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_script_add_data/)**