# Register and enqueue conditional (browser-specific) javascript files?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

The WP.SE community has always advised the use of `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` for adding scripts in a theme/template (and likewise, `wp_register_style` and `wp_enqueue_style` for stylesheets).

---

This is how I register and enqueue my scripts...

**First, I add something like this in functions.php**

```
add_action('init','wpse54189_register_script');
function wpse54189_register_script(){

    //Register scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'aahan_bootstrap_transition', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap-transition.js');
    wp_register_script( 'aahan_bootstrap_carousel', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap-carousel.js', array('aahan_bootstrap_transition'));    
    wp_register_script( 'wpse54189_ajax_comment', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/no-reload-comments.js');
}
```

**then call it in a template file (say, header.php) like this**

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'aahan_bootstrap_carousel' ); ?>
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse54189_ajax_comment' ); ?>
```

---

Now, coming to the point, how do I register and enqueue "conditional JavaScript files" that are there to be recognized by specific browsers? For example:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

How do I register and enqueue this properly?

**PS:** I use the [Reddle theme](http://theme.wordpress.com/themes/reddle/), developed by the theme wranglers at Automattic. And the theme's header.php directly uses the just aforementioned code -- i.e. it's not enqueued. So, does that mean, it's the only way to do it?

Comment: Although almost an year old, this [same question was asked before](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/20873/10691). I didn't come across it when I searched earlier.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`WP_Scripts` and `WP_Styles` classes are behind `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` functions. If you take a look at classes implementation ([scripts](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/class.wp-scripts.php#L79) and [styles](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/class.wp-styles.php#L35)) then you will see that `WP_Scripts` class doesn't support any kind of conditional scripts, but! you can see that `WP_Styles` does! The problem is that `wp_enqueue_style` doesn't allow you to setup condition.

So we have to make a small hack:

```
add_filter( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse2345_enqueue_scripts' );
function wpse2345_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mystyle', 'url/of/my/style.css', array(), '1.0.0' );

    global $wp_styles;
    $wp_styles->registered['mystyle']->add_data( 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
}
```

Such hack become possible, because all registered styles are stored in `registered` field of `WP_Styles` class. Each of registered style is an object of `_WP_Dependency` class, which allow you to add extra data.

Unfortunately this hack is not working for scripts.

**Additional Information:**
I was actually going through the code in [Aaron Campbell's Essence Theme](https://github.com/aaroncampbell/Essence/blob/master/functions.php#L151) last night and noticed that he was calling both a browser conditional script and style.

```
/**
 * @var WP_Scripts
 */
global $wp_scripts;
// Conditionally load this only for IE < 9
$wp_scripts->add_data( 'html5', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

/**
 * @var WP_Styles
 */
global $wp_styles;
// Conditionally load this only for IE < 8
$wp_styles->add_data( 'blueprint-ie', 'conditional', 'lt IE 8' );
```

There is also a [ticket and patch but it's not in core yet](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16024).  Obviously the conditional script won't work without the patch but one thing to note is that you can use the add_data method directly inside your function that is attached to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action.

Comment: `Unfortunately this hack is not working for scripts.` Oh... that sucks! Looks like the only way is the way it is. :( Thanks for the hack by the way. :)

Comment: Looks like we have conditional scripts starting from 4.2 https://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/31223