# Enqueue script inside IE conditional comments

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I'm trying to include selectivizr.js inside conditional comments. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

  <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <?php
    function blarg(){
      wp_enqueue_script('selectivizr', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/vendor/selectivizr.js');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blarg', 101);
  ?>
  <![endif]-->

  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="<?php echo get_bloginfo('name'); ?> Feed" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_feed_link()); ?>">
</head>
```

Nothing appears between the comments. I'm using the Roots theme. They have a scripts.php where other scripts are queued. If I put the `wp_enqueue_script()` in that file it works, but then I can't do the conditional comments.

UPDATE:

OK, the real challenge seems to be getting a script inside conditional comments (or any other particular HTML) will still using the queuing system. What is the best way to do that? Or is there a way?

Comment: Looks like there may be some solution here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20873/wp-enqueue-script-adding-conditional-statement-not-working but I am sick of all of WP's complications and I think I may just include it plainly as Pieter suggests.

Comment: FYI, [this has been an issue being kicked around for years now](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16024).

Comment: Hmm, and it may not be worth resolving as people leave old IE and new versions don't support conditional comments anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <?php
    function blarg(){
      wp_enqueue_script('selectivizr', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/vendor/selectivizr.js');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blarg', 101);
  ?>
  <![endif]-->
```

to

```
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>

<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/js/vendor/selectivizr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<![endif]-->
```

`wp_enqueue_script()` should only be used in a `functions.php` file.

Comment: +1. Technically, it's not that `wp_enqueue_script()` *can* only be used in `functions.php`; rather, it is that it *must* be called *before* `wp_head()`, inside of which the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action is fired. By calling it *after* `wp_head()`, it can't/won't do anything, because `wp_enqueue_scripts` has already fired.

Comment: I did try putting it before wp_head() but that didn't work either... I see now that I have to have the `add_action(wp_enqueue_scripts...)` thing inside the functions.php or something that functions.php includes I guess. But then that still places the script outside the conditional comments. So is Pieter's solution the best/only way to get it inside conditional comments?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd refrain from using `wp_enqueue_scripts` unless you're in the functions.php file.

If you're looking to call this scripts exclusively on a certain page, you can use the `is_page()` function. Then to detect the browser and call the function conditionally, we'll use the global variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

```
function blarg(){
    if (is_page( 'Page_name' )){
        if (preg_match('/(?i)msie [6-8]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
            wp_enqueue_script('selectivizr', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/vendor/selectivizr.js');
        }
    }
}   
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blarg');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid adding scripts directly into a template and enqueue them from your theme functions.php or plugin or wherever you are storing your logic.

In this case you could write something like this in your blarg function:

```
wp_enqueue_script('selectivizr', get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/vendor/selectivizr.js', array(), '1.0', false);

wp_script_add_data( 'selectivizr', 'conditional', 'lte IE 8' );
```

By using the `wp_script_add_data` function you can choose whether the script runs right away, async with the page loading or deferred to the end (equivalent to putting the script in the footer) and most importantly you can wrap your conditional code around it.

see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_script_add_data/